# Rename page/tab title of the page that renders PDF in Grails

Tags: pdf, grails

I'm using Grails. I need to render a PDF in browser. Here is the working code:

```
    response.setContentType("application/pdf")
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline;filename='${fileName}.pdf'")
    response.outputStream << pdfFile.newInputStream()
```

PDF is rendered correctly, but the tab/page title is method name. E.g. for PDF rendering method pdfController/downloadPdf is used. Then the tab/page title is 'downloadPdf'. I'd like it to be the '${fileName}.pdf'. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to set content disposition as Attachment. My example also forces download in browser instead of opening it in tab.

```
Document documentInstance = Document.get(id) //get your document from somewhere
response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM")
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=\"${documentInstance.filename}\"") 
def outputStream = response.getOutputStream() 
outputStream << documentInstance.filedata outputStream.flush() 
outputStream.close() }
```

Comment: If I download this file now, its name is correct, e.g. '${fileName}.pdf', so here I have no problem. And forcing download is not an option for me, unfortunately.

Comment: I think the important line for was `response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment;Filename=\"${documentInstance.filename}\"")`

Comment: But attachment instead of inline parameter forces the download, while I need the pdf to be rendered in browser at first.